# Cannot change language on Ubuntu 16.04 with desktop LXDE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, language, lxde

This is how I change my language to German so far.

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-de language-pack-gnome-de
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)
sudo update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

For this steps I can only show some logs in German like below picture.
[picture of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/criHT.jpg)

But Icon still not change to German like below picture.
[pictrue of icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsyxy.jpg)

When I run `locale` it will give me back the settings like below picture.
[locale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKbbh.jpg)

How to change all the system into German?

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to add it's a port for amrhf. Settings, methods and software availability differs from the normal desktop/server (x86, x86_64) versions.

Comment: @MichaelBay I found that my `/etc/lxdm/Xsession` will `export $GREETER_LANGUAGE` to en_US.UTF-8.
This is the picture.
https://imgur.com/aTS8tUs
How can I change the GREETER_LANGUAGE?

Comment: Have a look at his one: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Spracheinstellungen/    You'll find a section about manual installation under Gtk-based systems like LXDE.